# pgRouting. pgr_ksp() returns -1 as id3

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

The documentation (http://docs.pgrouting.org/dev/src/ksp/doc/index.html) says that the result should be 0 for the last row. Is the same 0 than -1?

I'm new on this. Thaks for the help.

Comment: Which version of pgRouting do you use? Because there was just recently a change, which was merged into "develop" branch but the documentation might be not updated yet.